# What are the potential status codes for AWS Auto Scaling Activities?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Here is the documentation for the [Activity data type](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_Activity.html).

However, I think I've seen 4 status codes for the responses:

```
'Successful'
'Cancelled'
'InProgress'
'PreInProgress'
```

Are there any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they have updated the documentation, in [the same url](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_Activity.html) you have shared:

`Valid Values: WaitingForSpotInstanceRequestId | WaitingForSpotInstanceId | WaitingForInstanceId | PreInService | InProgress | Successful | Failed | Cancelled`